# How to package native library in Android app?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, libgdx

I'm trying unsuccessfully to include a pre-built library that uses native code in an Android app. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The contents of the finished .apk file look as follows. (I'm using NetBeans and Ant to build everything - I can include the relevant parts of the Ant script if anybody wants it.)

```
META-INF
assets
libs >
    armeabi >
        libandroidgl20.so
        libgdx.so
res 
AndroidManifest.xml
classes.dex
resources.arsc
```

In the application code, I have:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("gdx");
    System.loadLibrary("androidgl20");
}
```

But I keep getting the error: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library gdx not found`.

Am I putting the .so files in the right place? Do I need to do anything else to make sure the runtime is aware of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.load() requires the exact path (including full name) to the shared object. This is what you're doing wrong.

Use `System.loadLibrary("gdx");` instead.

Comment: This is correct, but I'm still getting the error. So it must be something else in addition to that.

Comment: Can you verify that the libraries are getting placed in your /data/data/(package.name)/lib directory?

Comment: Got it! It was a combination of two errors: not using loadLibrary, as you pointed out, and naming the directory 'libs' instead of 'lib'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all the dependencies of 'gdx' are met ?
Is there any unimplemented native function in that library ?

Comment: There were only two .so files included in the libgdx distribution, and I have both of them - so it should be safe to assume that all dependencies are met.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html this is what the documentation says. Try using ldd(or some thing similar) and be very clear about dependencies. Also check if all the native functions are implemented ...